# Linux - client_body_in_file_only - how to set file permissions for the temp file?

Tags: file, nginx, temp

We use the client_body_in_file_only option with nginx, to allow file upload via Ajax.  The config looks like this:

```
location ~ ^(\/path1|\path2)$ {

  limit_except POST { deny all; }
  client_body_temp_path      /path/to/app/tmp;
  client_body_in_file_only   on;
  client_body_buffer_size    128K;
  client_max_body_size       1000M;

  #this option is a quick hack to make sure files get saved on (ie this type of request goes to) on a specific server
  proxy_pass                 http://admin;
  proxy_pass_request_headers on;
  proxy_set_header           X-FILE $request_body_file;
  proxy_set_body             off;
  proxy_redirect             off;

  # might not need?
  proxy_read_timeout         3m;
}
```

This works, but the web server process (Mongrel) that handles the request has to `sudo` the temp file that comes through in `headers['X-FILE']`, before it can do anything with it.  This is because the temp file comes through with `600` permissions.

I'm not happy with this approach, which requires us to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file to allow the web server user to do `sudo chmod` without a password. It feels very unsecure.

Is there a way, with the nginx config, to change the permissions on the temp file that is created, eg to 775?

EDIT:  I just tried changing the value of the `umask` option in the nginx init config, then restarting nginx, but it didn't help.  It had been at `0022`, I changed it to `0002`.  In both cases it comes through with 600 permissions.

EDIT2: I also tried adding this line under the `proxy_redirect` line, in the nginx config.

```
proxy_store_access user:rw group:rw all:r;
```

But, it didn't make any difference - it still just has `user:rw`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking through the `nginx` source, it appears that the only mechanism that would modify the permissions of the temporary file is the `request_body_file_group_access` property of the request, which is consulted in [`ngx_http_write_request_body()`](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/55b37eff8f700ea1dd279368d5a4a7b00f3c1344/src/http/ngx_http_request_body.c#L459):

```c
if (r->request_body_file_group_access) {
    tf->access = 0660;
}
```

But even that limits you to `0660` and it seems that it is not a user-settable property, only being utilized by the `ngx_http_dav` module.

The permissions are ultimately set in [`ngx_open_tempfile()`](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/32c7bd5102571ec20e45f620d2916e612e3b2016/src/os/unix/ngx_files.c#L277), where they default to `0600`:

```c
fd = open((const char *) name, O_CREAT|O_EXCL|O_RDWR, access ? access : 0600);
```

So it seems that there is currently no configuration-based solution. If you're willing/able to build `nginx` from source, one possibility is to apply a simple patch to set the permissions to whatever you want in `ngx_http_write_request_body()`:

```
+    tf->access = 0644;
+
     if (r->request_body_file_group_access) {
         tf->access = 0660;
     }

     rb->temp_file = tf;
```

I tested this and obtained the following, the first file having been uploaded without the modification, and the second file with it:

```
$ ls -al /tmp/upload/
total 984
drwxr-xr-x  2 nobody root     12288 Feb 18 13:42 .
drwxrwxrwt 16 root   root     12288 Feb 18 14:24 ..
-rw-------  1 nobody nogroup 490667 Feb 18 13:40 0000000001
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nogroup 490667 Feb 18 13:42 0063184684
```

Comment: I'm marking this correct as it seems the only solution is to rebuild nginx.

Answer (score 3):

It seems, that it is not possible at the moment to configure the file permissions, but there is an [official feature request](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1651).

> The file permissions are always 0600 making the application unable to read the file at all. [...] This is currently an unsupported scenario: [Nginx] creates the temporary file with the default permissions [...] 0600 (unless `request_body_file_group_access` is set - but unfortunately that property is not settable).

The ticket was opened in October 2018 with minor priority.